# Foreach loop for listing unmanaged disks in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, loops, foreach, disk

It's very easy to list azure managed disks in PS, but unmanaged ones are very tricky to list, as they're not objects from azure POV. I tried to wrote foreach loop to list me all unamanged disks (i.e. *.vhd files) for each storage account. This is the code I wrote:

```
$StorageAccounts = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount
$sa = $StorageAccounts | foreach-object {

#Get the Management key for the storage account
$key1 = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -name $_.StorageAccountName)[0].value
 
#Get the Storage Context to access the Storage Container
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $_.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $key1
 
#Get the Storage Container in the Variable
$storageContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $storageContext

$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $storageContainer.name -Context $storageContext 

 [PSCustomObject]@{
 "Name" = $blob.Name
 "Length" = $blob.Length
 "Storage Account Name" = $_.StorageAccountName
}
}
```

I want the loop to fetch all the vhd's for each storageaccount and parse it into pscustomobject to list me all vhd*s from all storage accounts, but I get an error:

> Get-AzureStorageBlob : Cannot validate argument on parameter
> 'Container'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that
> is not null or empty, and then try the command again. At line:13
> char:41
>
> Get-AzureStorageBlob : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
> 'System.String' required by parameter 'Container'. Specified method is not > supported.
> At line:13 char:41

Why loop is not parsing data to $storageContainer in line 11? I can see what's inside other two vars like $key1 and $storageContext.

Comment: because the $storageContainer.name will return an array since many containers can be in one storage account.

Comment: So what you're proposing, another loop for Get-AzureStorageBlob cmdlet? But how this loop should look like, so it could parse data to table variable?

Comment: Yes, write another loop, and I think the answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rewrite your script in this fashion:

```
$StorageAccounts = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount
$StorageAccounts.foreach{
    $ctx = $_.Context
    $containers = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx
    $containers.foreach{
        $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $_.name -Context $ctx
        $blobs.foreach{
            do_something
        }
    }
}
```

you dont need to get keys to construct context, because storage account variable contains the context. and then you need to iterate containers and blobs